# how to access all filenames from a remote server folder - c#?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have many images on remote server say images.foo.com/222 & i want to access file names of all files that resides in the folder 222 on images.foo.com/.
i have tried following code but getting error "virtual path is not valid" :

```
imageserver = http://images.foo.com/222;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(imageserver); // line giving exception
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles();
string simagename = ""; 
if (rgFiles.Count() > 0)
{
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
//collect each filename from here
}
}
```

Please help
thanks in advance
gbaxi

Comment: Using the Direction.GetFiles() or new DirectoryInfo class is only useful for local or network file systems. Http is a web based protocol and thus not able to be browsed. You could look at using WebDev?

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Spideroo.aspx or http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Pulling-Data-From-Internet-URLs-in-C/

Answer (score 2):

DirectoryInfo need a UNC path of type "\\fileserver\images"

A http address will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a directory residing on the web with the DirectoryInfo class. Instead, use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class to get a list from the URL and get the files from that list.

Comment: hi ,can you please tell me how i can do it using webrequest class

Comment: @user255818: You will have to parse the response data manually from the URL using [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx). An example is available in the link, when using HttpWebRequest. Get a response from your image site, and then put individual responses (don't forget to dispose them) to each of your files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTTP does not have a clear interface on how a directory listing is being displayed. There are roughly two choices:

1. Parse the HTML retrieved through a WebRequest, but you won't get things like creation/modification time and user;
2. Go with a different mechanism to retrieve the file details like FTP or File share.